# In SAS, how to add vref to a plot by taking value from proc sql (i.e. vref = x)

Tags: sas, proc-sql

Code:

```
data star;
input y x ;
datalines;
 0.6 3.4
 0.4 1.8
 0.6 3.1
 0.8 0.2
 3.6 1.2
 1.2 2.4
 8.1 3.0
 6.0 6.4
;
run;
     PROC SQL;
     SELECT Mean(x) AS meanx
     FROM star;
     QUIT;


    proc gplot data=star;
    plot y*x /vref= &meanx.;
    run;
    quit;
```

I am trying to add vref to plot using mean calculated in proc sql as "plot y*x1 /vref= &meanx1.;" but it is giving me error. can anyone help me. Thanks in advance

Comment: For graphing you shouldn't use GPLOT anymore, SGPLOT has way more functionality for this type of thing. For example you can have it as a variable in your dataset or hardcoded similarly.

Comment: good to know thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `proc sql`, you need to use the keyword `into`, followed by a colon, to create a macro variable.

```
PROC SQL;
 SELECT Mean(x1) into :meanx1
 FROM star;
 QUIT;
```